# Disable and enable audio output from the command line

Tags: command-line, sound

I want to enable and disable an audio output from the command line. I am aware that I can do so from the GUI, but I am looking for a way to do this from the command line.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is a jack file? What does it have to do with USB? You should [edit] your question, and ask **what** you want to do, not speculate on how to do it.

Comment: In my opinion turning on and off pretty much refers to enable and disable correct ?... I can’t find anything online about the built in jack file, module or enabling and disabling without the internet saying download jack

Comment: @vidarlo  Certain files can control behavior of actual hardware. Particular example of that would be writing particular value of brightness to `/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` file, which is what OP was kinda suggesting before  your edit.   Obviously OP's English isn't that good, but that's basically what they meant.

Comment: @Jojo  There's command-line applications for controlling audio that come with Ubuntu already. Particularly , `alsamixer`. Give it a try. As for particular  device file to control audio, I don't think there's none or at least not to my knowledge

Comment: That’s just it, I don’t want a gui, I want to be able to control the module that’s linked to a file but I’m not sure where it’s at...

Comment: @Jojo `alsamixer` isn't GUI, it's command-line text-based interface. There's also  `amixer` which is just a single command, so you could use `amixer set Master 50%` to set volume to 50% for example.   I've checked how it works, but it doesn't seem to write to any special file, so I think it communicates with a driver only. Good question, but I think it won't have the answer you want.

Comment: So I found out that the jack doesn’t come with a file, but the pcm.jack can be set in a program, is there a way to stop or start this pcm directly

Comment: Maybe not, all the alsa files point to pcm.jack but pcm.jack is not in lib/modules

Comment: I'd alsu suggest looking into `pactl` and `pacmd` which controls pulseaudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At pulseaudio level:

> pactl list sinks |egrep -e 'Sink|State|Mute'

Example of output:

```
Sink #0
           State: SUSPENDED
           Mute: yes 
Sink #1
           State: RUNNING
            Mute: yes
```

Current audio output is #1. So toggle it:

> pactl set-sink-mute 1 toggle

At alsa level:

> amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle

Comment: +1 I prefer `pactl set-sink-mute 1 yes` or `pactl set-sink-mute 1 no`

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T.

Type `sudo apt install pavucontrol` and press Enter. This command will install the PulseAudio Volume Control application.

Open the PulseAudio Volume Control application.

Click on the Configuration tab.

Find your digital output device (e.g., headphones) and set its profile to Off.

Comment: The OP asks for a command line option (usable with a shortcut possibly). Pavucontrol is useful, but not here.